# Bad html formatting with jQuery.html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something that I can't understand and i'm struggling with that for 2 days.
For the story, I'm using VICOPO api to get zipcode/city (France only I think).
The thing is that the code I'm generating is not really good interpreted by jQuery (or maybe I'm doing it wrong)
Here is the code:

```
$('#postcode').val($('#postcode').val().toUpperCase());

    if ($('#postcode').val().length == 5)
    {
        var $ville = $('#postcode');    
        $.vicopo($ville.val(), function (input, cities) {

          if(input == $ville.val() && cities[0]) {

          if (cities.length == 1)
            $('#city').val(cities[0].city);
          else
          {
              var html = '';                                
              html += '<div style=\'text-align:center\'>';

              for (var i=0; i<cities.length; i++)
              {
                 var v = cities[i].city;
                 // --- HERE IS MY PROBLEM ---
                 html += '<p onclick=\'alert(\'' + v + '\');\'>' + v + '</p>';
              }                             

              html += '</div>';

              console.log(html);

              $('#multi_ville').html(html);
        }
    }
 });
```

When I inspect the elements in the multi_div this is what I get:

```
<p onclick="alert(" billey');'>BILLEY</p>
<p onclick="alert(" flagey-les-auxonne');'>FLAGEY-LES-AUXONNE</p>
etc ....
```

And when I inspect the console log, all looks correct:

```
<p onclick='alert('BILLEY');'>BILLEY</p>
<p onclick='alert('FLAGEY-LES-AUXONNE');'>FLAGEY-LES-AUXONNE</p>
<p onclick='alert('VILLERS-LES-POTS');'>VILLERS-LES-POTS</p>
etc ....
```

If someone have an idea or what I'm doing wrong, it would cool.

(may I mention, this code is in a smarty tpl file surrounded with the {literal} tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create [self closed](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) tags via jquery and then append them to `#multi_ville`, here is an example:

```
// create div element
var div = $('<div/>', {
    'style' : 'text-align:center'
});

for (var i=0; i<cities.length; i++)
{
    var v = cities[i].city;

    // create p element with click event and then append it to div
    $('<p/>').on('click', function() { 
        alert(v); 
    }).text(v).appendTo(div);

}                             

$('#multi_ville').append(div);
```

**EDIT** It seems that my code above always alert the last city when we click on  a element, that's because `alert` takes the value that `v` variable has at the time it runs, to solve this we can use let statement:

```
let v = cities[i].city;
```

Or a function:

```
for (var i=0; i<cities.length; i++) {

    var v = cities[i];

    createPTag(v, div);

}

function createPTag(v, div) {

    $('<p/>').on('click', function() { 
        alert(v); 
    }).text(v).appendTo(div);

}
```

Comment: Nice one ! but the problem now is that when i click on an element, it's always the text of the last one.

Comment: I see, You could resolve this by using `let v = cities[i].city` or use function inside the loop that accept `v` as argument, I updated my answer

Comment: Glad it helped,

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
html += '<p onclick=\'alert(\'' + v + '\');\'>' + v + '</p>';
```

try this:

```
html += '<p onclick="alert(\'' + v + '\');">' + v + '</p>';
```

[Here's some info](http://2ality.com/2012/09/javascript-quotes.html) on when and how to use double/single quotes.

EDIT:

Also, check the `else` on this `if` statement:

```
if (cities.length == 1)
```

You need a closing curly bracket (`}`) to close in the `else`. It should be added directly after this line:

```
$('#multi_ville').html(html);
```

Comment: Thanks, but still have : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: @Stv, you missed `}` at the top if. Here is the correct code: https://jsfiddle.net/g372p837/1. Remember write a beautiful code and you never get this error again.

Comment: @Anh, nothing is missing else i will have an error before, the thing is, the injected code in the div is not the same i'm generating (as i can see in the console)

Comment: Does the `alert(v)` shows up when you click on one of those elements?

Comment: Nope, as v is a string it need to be surrounded by single quote so i have
alert(BILLEY); and then BILLEY is undefined.